# How to perform fuzzy match with Excel Add-on focusing on specific keyword

Tags: function, excel, vba

I have the Fuzzy Match extension from Microsoft that creates tables based on specified columns and provides the best match to an entry from table 1 from table X and provides a score as well. My concern is the hierarchy of keywords being matched - by that I mean, there are specific keywords that I would like the fuzzy match add-on to say "if this keyword is NOT present, do not bother attempting a fuzzy match". I also want to remove filler, such as "and" and "or" and even specific keywords that I deem irrelevant in scoring but still show up alot. Maybe I need to run a VBA script, but whatever the case, I hope someone can help me with this question.

Comment: Your question would be improved with examples of data & expected results, as well as any code you've tried that didn't quite do what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to clean your data *before* you run the Fuzzy Match on it, either manually, with formulas, with VBA, or with PowerQuery.

To do it manually, filter your data to only include terms that contain your keywords, copy and paste to a new sheet, use Find and Replace to remove " and " as well as  " or " (note the spaces) in both your source data and your match data with "", and run the Fuzzy Match extension.

With formulas, you pretty much do the same thing, but using formulas to transform the Lookup column so that if it doesn't contain the keywords the formula returns `=NA()` and then wrap that in a couple of SUBSTITUTE functions that replace " and " as well as " or " with "", perform that last step with you lookup data, and run the Fuzzy Match extension.